# tf.browser.fromPixels returns all zeros from img element

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

I am using `tensorflowjs` to do some front-end image classification. I am trying to use [tf.browser.fromPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.2/#browser.fromPixels) to convert an img element to a tensor. However, I am getting all zeros of shape `[160, 160, 3]`. I am using the `FileReader` api to read an image from the file system via the `<input type="file">` element. Here's some of the code:

```
function getFiles(event) {
  const files = event.target.files;
  let tempStore = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    tempStore.push(files[i]);
  }
  return tempStore;
}
```

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById("upload");
  imageElement.addEventListener("change", event => {
    const files = getFiles(event);
    Promise.all(files.map(loadImg)).then(d => {
      console.log("All done !!!", d);
    });
  });
```

```
const loadImg = imgFile => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
    reader.onload = async e => {
      imgEl.src = e.target.result;
      imgEl.setAttribute("width", 160);
      imgEl.setAttribute("height", 160);
      document.body.append(imgEl);
      const fromPixels = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgEl);
      resolve(fromPixels);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
  });
};
```

The image gets appended to document body properly. 
The imageElement is of the form:
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,....." width=160 height=160>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the tensor from the image when the `img` tag has not yet been loaded. Here is the way to go

```
  imgEl.src = e.target.result;
  imgEl.setAttribute("width", 160);
  imgEl.setAttribute("height", 160);
  document.body.append(imgEl);
  im.onload = () => {
   // create the tensor after the image has loaded
    const fromPixels = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgEl);
    resolve(fromPixels);
  }
```